# Specifying a custom position for the vaadin notification

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I went through the javadocs for the Notification class and came across this

```
In addition to the basic pre-configured types, a Notification can also be configured to show up in a custom position, for a specified time (or until clicked), and with a custom stylename
```

this is exactly what I want

I have a TextField component (in the center of the screen) and I want the notification to show up to the right of it (with some margin). How do I achieve this?

the setPosition() method accepts an enum so how exactly do you specify something other than the pre-configured Position types?

Comment: Someone may correct me, but it's my understanding that you can only display a notification window in the locations specified here: http://vaadin.com/download/prerelease/7.0/7.0.0/7.0.0.rc2/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/Notification.html unless you really want to work some CSS magic

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot position a Notification relative to a component. There is one addon called [ContextHelp](https://vaadin.com/addon/contexthelp), which may provide functionality you need.

Comment: yea I was using ContextHelp originally actually but found some issues with it including one where it didn't work with the current 7.4.0 rc1. Its not being actively maintained either so decided to go back to the Notification. So do you think that line in the Javadocs where it says you can set custom position might be incorrect?

Comment: I guess custom position refers to the setPosition method. The PopupExtension addon might also be worth of testing: https://vaadin.com/addon/popupextension